# I would like to create a custom menu using LibGDX. it's possible?

Tags: libgdx

my menu would be like this image when touch a color an action would be held.
it is possible to do this?

[this is the menu style :: click](https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Original_buzz_png/png/256/Google-Buzz-shape.png)

**help...**

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please give us as many informations as possible, as this would help us helping you. Also try to search for your problem before posting on Stackoverflow. I suggest you to read the Libgdx wiki (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki) before starting to develop games. For menus you may takt a look at `Scene2Dui`. IF thats not enough, you may use TWL.

Comment: You can draw images, write text, collect touches...you have everything you need with libGDX to create any kind of custom interface including menu.